# Control Visual Studio using python

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am building an application in which I would like to control Visual Studio, or at least have access to its compilation and build functionalities using (hopefully) python. I know Visual Studio macros are possible and available but it appears they are in .NET ([see doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb187340(v=vs.80).aspx)). Since I would like to automate what I want to do with VS in python I'm looking more for something along the lines of:

```
import vs2016 as controller
controller.build()
controller.compile()
```

Please note I am *not* looking to run python code in Visual Studio. This is an altogether different problem that is already widely [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-01-create-project) by Microsoft.

Is it possible to control Visual Studio within Python?

- if so, how?
- if not, what is a viable alternative? let's say I accept that it can only be done with dotnet. In this case how can I relay back to python while keeping it debuggable from a python script?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at using IronPython to talk to the .NET interface exactly the same way VB.NET or C# would? There are ways to access .NET from CPython, and some or all of the same interfaces might  be exposed to native code through COM, but either way, it won't be as simple (and as well documented with up-to-date examples) as the from-inside-.NET way.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a pretty big undertaking, but I would look in to a `win32com.client.dispatch` or `comtypes`to plug in to the COM object(there are several from a quick search and I dont know what any of them do)